# WPF DataGrid draws strange lines under the header and at the bottom of the table

Tags: datagrid

I make a style for DataGrid and ran into an unexpected problem. For some reason there is a line between the header and content, and this line is drawn exactly above the header. It is strange that if you set the templates ScrollViewer red color, then the line becomes reddish, as if there is some mixing.

[The line between the header and the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMenX.png)

[The line at the bottom of the header and at the bottom of the whole table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJvow.png)

I've already changed styles and templates, and how can not get rid of it.
Providing the DataGrid and Header styles

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Foreground}"/>
        <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCell_Standart}"/>
        <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRow_Standart}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer"
                            Focusable="false">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <!-- Left Column Header Corner -->
                                        <Button
                                            Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                            Focusable="false"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle,
                                                                                          TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

                                        <!-- Column Headers -->
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter
                                            x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

                                        <!-- DataGrid content -->
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter
                                            x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                                        <ScrollBar
                                            x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" />

                                        <Grid
                                            Grid.Row="2"
                                            Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar
                                                x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />
                        </ScrollViewer>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource HeaderFooter}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Roboto}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource HeaderSmallFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineHeight" Value="{StaticResource HeaderSmallHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid Margin="8 0" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter Margin="0 5 0 5"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                            RecognizesAccessKey="True">

                            </ContentPresenter>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Grd_SortArrows">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <local:IconControl Icon="ArrowUp" 
                                                           Brush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                           Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                           x:Name="SortArrow_Ascending"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"           
                                                           />

                                <local:IconControl Icon="ArrowDown" 
                                                           Brush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                           Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                           x:Name="SortArrow_Descending"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"           
                                                           />
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>

                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow_Descending"  Property="local:IconControl.Brush" Value="{DynamicResource Disabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow_Descending" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="CanUserSort" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Grd_SortArrows" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow_Ascending" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow_Descending" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow_Ascending" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow_Descending" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```